# Suppress just bash job control messages in scripts (Aborted, Broken pipe)

Tags: bash, jobs, abort

I have the following setup:

aborter.cpp

```cpp
#include <cassert>
int main(int argc, char** argv) { assert(argc >= 2); return 0; }
// compiled to 'aborter'
```

test.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

function runpipe() {
    yes | aborter "$@"
    test $? -ne 0 || echo OK
}
runpipe "$@"
```

Running `test.sh 123` prints only `OK`. Running just `test.sh` outputs the following:

```
aborter: aborter.cpp:2: int main(int, char**): Assertion `argc >= 2' failed.
./test.sh: line 3:  2521 Broken pipe             yes
      2522 Aborted                 | aborter "$@"
```

How do I suppress the 'Broken pipe' and 'Aborted' job control lines output by bash in the second case?
I want the output to be just the C++ assert dump (the first line).

This should not require editing `aborter.cpp` or the `test.sh` interface.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: redirect error messages to `dev/null` instead of std output `runpipe "$@" 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I suppress the 'Broken pipe' and 'Aborted' job control lines output by bash in the second case?

Redirect bash stderr to null except for you process.

```
exec 3<&2 2>/dev/null
function runpipe() {
    yes | aborter "$@" 2>&3
    test $? -ne 0 || echo OK
}
runpipe "$@"
```